# Persisting data between benchmarks using BenchmarkDotNet

Tags: benchmarkdotnet

I'm trying to benchmark two databases (different types, different locations).
My select benchmarks are working fine, but I'm having trouble with my inserts, updates and deletes.

I tried saving the key (`GUID`) I use for the insert in a class field of type `Queue<string>` but when my update benchmark is run this field is reset and thus empty, the same in my delete benchmark.
I don't want to call the delete statement after the insert statement in my insert benchmark or an insert statement in my delete benchmark because then the time results are off.

How to handle this situation?
I thought of creating a list of GUIDs in the `[GlobalSetup]` but when I change the number of iterations I need to increase or decrease this list.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this myself by saving the keys in a text file on GlobalCleanup and reading this file on GlobalSetup.